# Expand content div height to left-menu height when adding more item to menu

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have a left-menu in which I can add or remove item to. On the right there is a content div that has a min-height.

When adding more item into the left-menu using angular, I want the content div expand it height to the left-menu if the left-menu is taller than it's min-height.

One more thing is I also want the pull-down effect of ng-animate for the content div.

Here is the fiddle link: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bnlinhlang/babvqx8e/17/)

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['foo', 'bar']; 
  var num = 0;    
  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.items.push(num);
    num++;
  }
});
```

```css
#left {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-height: 200px
}

.item {
  height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.item.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;    
}

.item.ng-enter-active {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div id="left">
    <p class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{item}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <button ng-click="add()">add</button>
    {{names}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for hacky DOM manipulation using jQuery or `ng-style`. Just add `display: flex` to the wrapper:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/babvqx8e/26/

Using flexbox also allows you to remove the floats:

```
#left {
    width: 25%;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#right {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    min-height: 200px
}
```

See this [really nice guide to Flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$("#right").css({'height': $("#left").outerHeight()});
```

It will set the height of #right to outer height of #left.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, could you add it to my fiddle?

Comment: You need to add a link to jquery. I don't know much angular and how to add jquery to angular, google it maybe you fill find a way.

Answer (score 0):

So I will answer my question. I managed to do it using the ng-style directive:

`<div id="right" ng-style="{height: hgt+ 'px'}">`

Then in the controller:

`$scope.hgt = $('#left').outerHeight() + 40;`

http://jsfiddle.net/babvqx8e/22/

Comment: That's not a good way to achieve what you want.  You're manipulating the DOM from within the controller, which in Angular is a very Bad Thing to do.  See my answer for a better solution.

Comment: DOM manipulation best practices in Angular: http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/.